# on event is not working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to run the following code:

```
var eligible = Backbone.Model.extend({
        validate : function(attrs,options){
            //alert("ldsafh");
            if(attrs.min < attrs.max) {
                return "not eligible for voting";
            }   
        }

    });

        var age = new eligible({
            advice : "You are "
        });


        age.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
            alert("sfndxgj");
            console.log(model.get('advice') + " " + error);
        });

        age.set({
            min : 18,
            max : 100
        });
```

why this age.on event is not working?
Please help me out here ....

Comment: Did not know there was a max voting age... I learned something today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `{validate:true}` as option in set.

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true} is passed

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

**Note**: `invalid` event is available only after upgrading to Backbone 1.0. See [Change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

Comment: You would still need to ensure you're using the 1.0 version of Backbone.js, though, since the `"invalid"` event appears to be an addition since the 0.9 series (see [Upgrading](http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading))

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling [`age.set()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) instead of [`age.save()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) which invokes the `validate` method for you.

Comment: Are you passing the `min` and `max` arguments to `save` like you were doing with `set`?

Comment: what i did just replace the set with save in above code...nothing else

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing what @StuartM suggested.  I get the alert.  http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/k8t5P/

Comment: Do you see anything in the `console.log` output?

Comment: Can you include the full HTML of your test page either in the question or in a [Pastie](http://pastie.org) ?

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of Backbone?  That fiddle is using the latest version. I copied/pasted your code exactly and changed `set` to `save`.  You must have something else... did you clear your browser cache?